# Do I need to import the process module of nodejs or leave it as such?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I've seen that the process modules can be used without importing it directly in your file as said in the documentation from 2011. https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/the-process-module/

> The process module doesn't need to be required - it is somewhat
> literally a wrapper around the currently executing process, and many
> of the methods it exposes are actually wrappers around calls into core
> C libraries.

But in the documentation of `Node.js v16.17.1` (the one I'm using) they actually import it without mentioning it. https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/process.html#process-events

```
import process from 'node:process';

process.on('beforeExit', (code) => {
  console.log('Process beforeExit event with code: ', code);
});
```

Is there even a difference between the two ? If I use the import syntax will it be referencing the current process or a different instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`process`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/v16.17.1/src) is available without export. For consistency it is **re-exported** as a module [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v16.17.1/lib/process.js)

Two things to keep in mind:

- Child processes (`spawn`/`exec`) return their own process object.
- For `Worker`s, within `worker` body, `process` returns the owner `process`, as these are just threads.